# Slow when stream video from supabase storage

Tags: flutter, supabase

I always get lag or buffer when playing video (size 28 Mb) from supabase storage in my mobile application. Every each lag can takes about 1 or 2 seconds, its not good for UX. I'm in free tier, if pro plan can resolve my problem, i will upgrade my subscription.

Can anyone explain what happened? or same experience as me?

> Test in real devices : Samsung A50 and Realme 8
>
> Connection speed (speed.googlefiber.net) :
>
> 1. 215 ping to Los Angeles
> 2. Download 16.4 Mbps
> 3. Upload 24.5 Mbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than a week, and finally i can resolve it. It isn't about supabase server, device, internet speed or free tier, but the problem come from the "video".

I change the bitrate of video to more lower using ffmpeg and it works.

> when converting a video for online streaming, a lower bitrate may help reduce load times.

Comment: After converting to a lower bitrate using ffmpeg, was the video format still the same? Also, does this confirm the fact that supabase offers video streaming by default and one doesn't need any extra effort?

Comment: @kadet (1) If you only change the bitrate, only that change will changes, others like format is same like original. But if we change the format or codec of video and make it more faster and light size, why not?. (2) Yuupp, you upload video in Supabase storage, then you can streaming it. And definitely faster because Supabase use cloudflare CDN.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to figure it out. I'm even going further to convert the videos to HLS before uploading on supabase as this helps make them a bit tricky to download.